# Can't bind multiple services on a local RMI registry

Tags: java, rmi

I'm building this software for a school assignment. A server (regulator) controls interactions between shops (distributors) and clients. I have three entities:

- Regulator. It binds two services: authentication (user control) and listing (lists distributors and their offers) to the registry.
- Distributor. Deploys a user interface that allows registering and deleting offers and binds a service (`ServiceSales`) to the registry.
- Client. Deploys a user interface and allows the user to ask the regulator which distributor has the offer they are interested in.

The regulator binds both the services fine, and the other entities interact ok with it. When I'm trying to bind `ServiceSales` I get an error as if the registry wasn't up.

This is the relevant code in the class `Regulator`:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
Utils.setCodeBase(ServiceSalesInterface.class);
ServiceSalesInterface sales = new ServiceSalesImpl(servicio);
ServicioVentaInterface sales_remote = 
     (ServiceSalesInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(sales, 8888);
registry.rebind(sales.name(), sales_remote);
```

`sales.name()` returns service's name.

This is `Utils` source:

```
public class Utils {

    public static final String CODEBASE = "java.rmi.server.codebase";

    public static void setCodeBase(Class<?> c){

        String path = c.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
                .getLocation().toString();

        String cbase = System.getProperty(CODEBASE);

        if (path != null && !path.isEmpty()){

            path = path + " " + cbase;

        }

        System.setProperty(CODEBASE, path);    
    }
}
```

I've tried using different ports but it doesn't seem to be that what it is causing the error. This is the error message that pops when I'm trying to bind `ServiceSales` to the registry ( `registry.rebind(sales.name(), sales_remote);` ):

> java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
>       at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)

In case it is needed, this is the relevant code within the `Regulator` class (that works fine).

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","127.0.0.1");
registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(8888);

Utils.setCodeBase(ServiceGoods.class);
ServiceGoodsInterface goods = new ServiceGoodsImpl();
ServiceGoodsInterface goods_remote =  
    (ServiceGoodsInterface)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(goods, 8888);
registry.rebind("ServiceGoods", goods_remote);

Utils.setCodeBase(ServiceAuth.class);
ServiceAuthInterface auth = new ServiceAuthImpl();
ServiceAuthInterface auth_remote = 
    (ServiceAuthInterface)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(auth, 8888);
registry.rebind("ServiceAuth", auth_remote);

System.out.println("Server is running.");
```

Comment: You haven't started the Registry on port 1099 in the first example.

Comment: So if I'm using different classes I should start the registry for each class even though everything is running in the same machine?

Comment: I didn't say so. If you are trying to bind to a Registry on port 1099, you need to start a Registry on port 1099. If you're trying to bind to a Registry on port 8888, you need to start a Registry on port 8888, and you have. You don't need multiple Registries: one will do, and you may as well use port 1099 which is already reserved for the purpose.

Comment: If you want to run a custom registry port from within your server app you may use this example, sometimes things are easier this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/38440857/185565

Comment: Can't expand right now because I'm on my phone, but what I ended doing was to create another registry for the `Regulator` service, binding it to a different port and that did it for me

Comment: Why? You only need one Registry in a host.